# How to apply chisq.test of independence to each dataframe in a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, lapply, chi-squared

I would like to apply the chisq.test of independence (chisq.test(x)) to each df of a list successively, but I always get an Error message telling me that "all entries of 'x' must be non negative and finite", whereas they are actually all negative and finite. I think it is because it treats all my data as character or because in each df my forst column is made of characters, but I don't really know how to solve it... (I am quite new to R).

```r
# Creating the list of dataframes
install.packages("datapasta")

my_data <- tibble::tribble(
                                               ~UC, ~Fr_term, ~Fr_other_terms,
                              "reference scenario",                  0L,                    2168L,
                              "reference scenario",                224L,                    5158L,
                              "reference scenario",                 19L,                    2247L,
                               "capacity building",                 65L,                    2168L,
                               "capacity building",                 52L,                    5158L,
                               "capacity building",                  0L,                    2247L,
                              "evolution scenario",                184L,                    2168L,
                              "evolution scenario",                273L,                    5158L,
                              "evolution scenario",                  0L,                    2247L,
                                   "carbon market",                 37L,                    2168L,
                                   "carbon market",                  0L,                    5158L,
                                   "carbon market",                 17L,                    2247L
                              )

  
my_data <- split(my_data, my_data$UC) # I split the dataframe into a list of several df 

lapply(my_data, chisq.test) # try to apply chi2 of independence...

#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite
```

Precision : my data are already in the form of a contingency table, hence my not specifying the variables when applying the chisq.test() function

Answer (score 1):

Specify the variables in `chisq.test`.

```
result <- lapply(my_data, function(x) chisq.test(x$Fr_term, x$Fr_other_terms))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1 - saving statistics in the data.frame

```
my_data %>% 
   nest(-UC) %>%
   group_by(UC) %>%
   mutate(
      test = map(.x = data,~broom::tidy(chisq.test(.x$Fr_term,.x$Fr_other_terms)))
      ) %>% 
   unnest(test)
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   UC [4]
  UC                 data             statistic p.value parameter method                    
  <chr>              <list>               <dbl>   <dbl>     <int> <chr>                     
1 reference scenario <tibble [3 x 2]>         6   0.199         4 Pearson's Chi-squared test
2 capacity building  <tibble [3 x 2]>         6   0.199         4 Pearson's Chi-squared test
3 evolution scenario <tibble [3 x 2]>         6   0.199         4 Pearson's Chi-squared test
4 carbon market      <tibble [3 x 2]>         6   0.199         4 Pearson's Chi-squared test
```

### Solution 2 - printing the tests for each UC

```
my_data %>% 
   group_split(UC) %>% 
   map(.f = function(x) chisq.test(x$Fr_term, x$Fr_other_terms))
```

#### Output

```
[[1]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x$Fr_term and x$Fr_other_terms
X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991


[[2]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x$Fr_term and x$Fr_other_terms
X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991


[[3]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x$Fr_term and x$Fr_other_terms
X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991


[[4]]

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x$Fr_term and x$Fr_other_terms
X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to do the chisq.test of independence (chisq.test(x)), not the Pearson's one :/

Comment: They are the same @PaulineBureau

Comment: I am not sure I understand then, because when I try chisq.test(df) et chisq.test(df$x, df$y), I obtain two different results, and it is the first one that is correct to me ... Here is an exemple of this comparison using a simple dataframe :

Comment: u <- c(2, 28, 53)
v <- c(8445, 14853, 20452)

df <-data.frame(u,v)
df
#>    u     v
#> 1  2  8445
#> 2 28 14853
#> 3 53 20452
chisq.test(df)
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  df
#> X-squared = 17.452, df = 2, p-value = 0.0001623
chisq.test(df$u, df$v)
#> Warning in chisq.test(df$u, df$v): Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  df$u and df$v
#> X-squared = 6, df = 4, p-value = 0.1991

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to pass a whole `data.frame` as contingency table into `chisq.test()`

```r
library(dplyr)

lapply(unique(my_data$UC), function(x) {
  my_data %>% 
    filter(UC == x) %>% 
    select(-UC) %>% 
    chisq.test(.)
})

#> [[1]]
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  .
#> X-squared = 143.59, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  .
#> X-squared = 83.697, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  .
#> X-squared = 167.75, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
#> 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> 
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  .
#> X-squared = 79.891, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Tidier solution using `tidy()` and merge the list with `rbindlist`

```r
lapply(unique(my_data$UC), function(x) {
  my_data %>% 
    filter(UC == x) %>% 
    select(-UC) %>% 
    chisq.test(.) %>% 
    broom::tidy() %>% 
    mutate(UC = x, .before = 1)
}) %>%
  data.table::rbindlist()

#>                    UC statistic      p.value parameter
#> 1: reference scenario 143.59031 6.603277e-32         2
#> 2:  capacity building  83.69708 6.689745e-19         2
#> 3: evolution scenario 167.75043 3.745051e-37         2
#> 4:      carbon market  79.89116 4.485962e-18         2
#>                        method
#> 1: Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 2: Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 3: Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 4: Pearson's Chi-squared test
```

Comment: It works perfectly on my_data, but when I apply it on my original dataframe, I get "incorrect argument type 'character'". So i guess I will just recreate my dataframe using tibble::tribble. Thanks a lot @rifset !!

Comment: @PaulineBureau You're welcome. If my answer solves your problem, kindly accept the answer as it might help someone else with a similar problem in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

If the data are already in the form of a contingency table, I apply the `chisq.test` without specifying variables, as follows:

```r
library(dplyr)

lapply(unique(my_data$UC), function(x) {
  my_data %>% 
    filter(UC == x) %>% 
    select(-UC) %>% 
    chisq.test(.)
})
```

Or as follows If I want to include my results in the df :

```
lapply(unique(my_data$UC), function(x) {
  my_data %>% 
    filter(UC == x) %>% 
    select(-UC) %>% 
    chisq.test(.) %>% 
    broom::tidy() %>% 
    mutate(UC = x, .before = 1)
}) %>%
  data.table::rbindlist()
```

If the data are not in the form of a contingency table, I need to make sure that I specify the variables when applying the `chisq.test` to the list, *i.e.* `chisq.test(x$Fr_term, x$Fr_other_terms)`.